# VB populate controller list

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I'm using this sample VB code to return a set of data rows to a table in an html page using MS Web API - and, it works perfectly.

```
 Public Class CalendarEventsController
    Inherits ApiController

    Private CalendarEvents As CalendarEvent() = New CalendarEvent() {
      New CalendarEvent() With {
      .id = 1,
      .eventName = "Event 1"
    }, New CalendarEvent() With {
            .id = 2,
            .eventName = "Event 2"
        }}
    ' GET api/<controller>
    Public Function GetCalendarEvents() As IEnumerable(Of CalendarEvent)
        Return CalendarEvents
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem is I need to populate this list with data from a DB.  I need some type of For Each loop to iterate through the DB rows and then create a corresponding row in the controller list.  I can't seem to construct such a loop.  Just getting this to work with i = 1 to i = 2 would be great.

Edit:  Working version:

```
     Public Class CalendarEventsController
    Inherits ApiController
    Public Function GetCalendarEvents() As IEnumerable(Of EventCalendar)
        Dim myContext As New RoutesEntities()
        Return From eventlist In myContext.EventCalendars Select eventlist
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Are you already able to retrieve the data from the database?  If so, how are you doing that?  The most sensible option would be to use a LINQ query, which pretty much wraps up a loop in a single line, to create your CalendarEvent objects but the details depend on exactly what data structure you have, e.g. typed DataSet or EF context or perhaps DTOs already derived from such.

Comment: jmcilhinney:  Thanks - that works fine.  I already had linq-EF6 code for the DB retrieval and didn't realize that a linq query would handle the data conversion details of my html side code:  $.getJSON("api/CalendarEvents".  Thanks very much - this really makes it easy.  I'm just learning this Web Api stuff and sometimes not seeing the obvious.